# select option from dropdown which was populated using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have populated dropdown using javascript. when I am trying to make one option as selected using code below, it is not getting selected. Option is there in the dropwdown. Please let me what is wrong here.

```
$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName option").filter(function(){return ($(this).text() == 'optionname');});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName").val('optionname')
```

> This will select the **option** having value = optionname
>
> **NOTE** make sure your option has
>    `<option value='optionname'> optionname </option>` in there in your select.

Answer (score 0):

The [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method will return a list of jQuery objects, in this case it will **return** a jQuery object, not **select** that element.

So your code should add `.attr('selected','true')` after `.filter`.

```
$("#MST_CPH_AddAppointment_ddlAptAssociateName option")
  .filter(function() {
    return ($(this).text() == 'optionname');
  })
  .attr('selected', 'true');
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with @M.Tanzil way. It seems easy as well.